# Performance Testing - Send requests to multiple clients (as many as 2000 unique IP address(s)) from a Server

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, spoofing

Performance Testing - Send requests to multiple(as many as 2000 unique) IP address(s) from a Server.

I had this requirement to simulate thousands of client(each listening on a unique IP Address) receiving data(FileUpload) from a Server. Each client instance(hosted on an IP) was expected to provide multiple endpoints(RequestMapping) that the Server could send http requests to.

In order to achieve it, I developed a simple web-application with one Servlet(to map web request) for each endpoint and used embedded light weight jetty server to receive file transfer from Enterprise Application. The Servlet just reads the file name (form-Field) without really persisting the file stream in order to improve response time.

Used IP spoofing on multiple machines where each machine would be having 100s of different IP-Alias created using netsh.
Launched the jetty instance on each system and thus simulated thousands of clients receiving files from one Server.

With this, just a few systems could easily simulate around 2000 clients(where each client having unique IP addresses) receiving files from Server.

Answer (score 2):

An easier way would be using [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/), it is possible to set an arbitrary "Source address" for the HTTP Request sampler

[image: JMeter IP Spoofing]

This way you will be able to mimic the requests originating from different IP addresses using single machine.

See [Using IP Spoofing to Simulate Requests from Different IP Addresses with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter) article for detailed configuration instructions and examples.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Dmitri's method for jMeter if all you want is mimic the source IPs. You can also try using the [Load Test Portal](https://www.apicasystem.com/load-testing/) by Apica to actually get access to thousands of real hosts across the world. This will give you the actual response time and network delay data without needing to spoof the IPs. Their scripting tool is called [ZebraTester](https://www.apicasystem.com/load-testing/tools/) which is similar to jMeter

Answer (score 0):

This is a built in feature of mature performance testing tools.  In some cases the capability has been there since before the turn of the century.   I am unsure of the reason to reinvent the wheel in this case.